# Detecting what changes osmosis does on osm planet database?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I have already imported a planet osm file in my postgresql database and have now configured a daily update with osmosis.

Is there any way to find out what changes osmosis did in the database?

I use a call like this:

```
osmosis --rri workingDirectory=.replicate_daily --sc \
      --wpc user="dbuser" database="osm_planet" password="dbpassword"
```

Comment: WHat kind of details do you want to know? Changed OSM objects or tainted map tiles?

Comment: My process runs currently for about 14 hours, I got a cpu use about 14% ... :-/ I'm interested in any any activity sign. The tile rendering isn't currently configured. A overview of changed osm object would be fine.

Comment: Sounds like I/O is your bottleneck. Take a look at the `wa` (wait) value in `top` or use `iotop` to see the current I/O activity of your process.

Comment: In the meantime it end with a psql error - my fault I don't install hstore extention in postgresql :-/